# Python regex/regular expression for INSERT INTO SELECT pattern

Tags: python, regex, expression, sql-insert

I am reading a file in Python using `import re', my code is

```
>import re
>fh = open(r"ABC.PACKAGE", "r").read()
>
>pattern_string = "INSERT INTO .*";
>
>for line in re.findall(pattern_string, fh):
>    
>print(line)
```

Now there three types of INSERT statements in my file like below

```
>2.  INSERT INTO CMS.TMP_SEARCH_TOKEN_CODES (
        SELECT TOKEN.CODE   
        FROM CMS.TOKEN 
        INNER JOIN CMS.VEHICLE_INFO ON TOKEN.VEHICLE_INFO_ID = VEHICLE_INFO.VEHICLE_INFO_ID
        AND VEHICLE_INFO.PLATE_NUMBER = P_VEHICLE_NO AND TOKEN.IS_ACTIVE = 1 AND VEHICLE_INFO.IS_ACTIVE = 1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT TOKEN.CODE   
        FROM CMS.TOKEN 
        INNER JOIN CMS.VEHICLE_LINK_DATA  ON VEHICLE_LINK_DATA.TOKEN_ID = TOKEN.TOKEN_ID
        AND PLATE_NUMBER = P_VEHICLE_NO AND TOKEN.IS_ACTIVE = 1 AND TOKEN.VEHICLE_LINK_TYPE_ID = 2
        AND VEHICLE_LINK_DATA.IS_ACTIVE = 1
        );                

>3. INSERT INTO CMS.MAPSEARCH_TABLE
                    SELECT DISTINCT
                            DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID ORDER BY  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID, ,
                            CUSTOMER_TYPE.AR_CUSTOMER_TYPE AS CUSTOMER_TYPE_NAME_AR  
                        FROM  
                            CUSTOMER
                            INNER JOIN CUSTOMER_STATUS ON CUSTOMER_STATUS.CUSTOMER_STATUS_ID=CUSTOMER.STATUS_ID 
                            AND  (CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID=P_CUSTOMERID  OR P_CUSTOMERID IS NULL)
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMER_TYPE ON CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID = CUSTOMER_TYPE.CUSTOMER_TYPE_ID
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN BENEFICIARY ON
                            (BENEFICIARY.CUSTOMER_ID = P_CUSTOMERID   OR P_CUSTOMERID IS NULL)
                            AND  CUSTOMER.CUSTOMER_ID = BENEFICIARY.CUSTOMER_ID
                        WHERE
                           (P_BENEFICIARYCODE IS NULL OR UPPER(BENEFICIARY.CODE) LIKE '%' ||UPPER(P_BENEFICIARYCODE)||'%')
                           AND(P_BENEFICIARYNAME IS NULL OR UPPER(BENEFICIARY.NAME) LIKE '%' ||UPPER(P_BENEFICIARYNAME)||'%')
                                       ORDER BY BENEFICIARY.BENEFICIARY_ID;
```

I want to print the queries which have pattern like 2 and 3 but I am not able to generate the regular expression. it should be something like start with INSERT INTO .* then either (SELECT( or SELECT( and end with semicolon.

I don't use SQL PARSER but want to do with regular expression

Comment: `..blah..blah` is omitting possibly critical information here.  In general, if you want to parse SQL code, you will need to write a _parser_.  Regex alone may not be up to doing the job.

Comment: I suggest you read up on regular expressions and give it a shot yourself. Then we can help if what you tried doesn't quite get you all the way there.

Comment: Please use [sql-parse](https://sqlparse.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming, that by `pattern like 2 and 3` you mean select based insert statements, you could try this:
`r"INSERT INTO[^;]*SELECT[^;]*;"`

*update* due to updated problem description

```
import re

data = """
1. INSERT INTO TABLE1 (id,name)VALUES('123','ABS',);
2. INSERT INTO TABLE1 (SELECT(..blah..blah));
5. UPDATE ...;
3. INSERT INTO TABLE1 SELECT(..blah..blah);
4. DELETE FROM ...;
5. INSERT INTO CMS.TMP_SEARCH_TOKEN_CODES ( 
       SELECT TOKEN.CODE 
         FROM CMS.TOKEN INNER JOIN CMS.VEHICLE_INFO ON TOKEN.VEHICLE_INFO_ID = VEHICLE_INFO.VEHICLE_INFO_ID UNION ALL SELECT TOKEN.CODE FROM CMS.TOKEN INNER JOIN CMS.VEHICLE_LINK_DATA ON VEHICLE_LINK_DATA.TOKEN_ID = TOKEN.TOKEN_ID );
6. UPDATE ....;
"""
pattern_string = r"INSERT INTO[^;]*SELECT[^;]*;"
q = re.findall(pattern_string, data, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
print(q)
```

*update* reading from/writing to file, removing newlines:

```
import os
import re

with open("ABC.PACKAGE", "r") as fin, open("OUT.SQL", "w") as fout:
    statements = re.findall(r"INSERT INTO[^;]*SELECT[^;]*;", fin.read(), re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
    statements = [re.sub(r'\r?\n|\s+', ' ', s) for s in statements]
    fout.write(os.linesep.join(statements))
```

Comment: extract only queries like 
         INSERT INTO CMS.TMP_SEARCH_TOKEN_CODES (
            SELECT TOKEN.CODE   
            FROM CMS.TOKEN 
            INNER JOIN CMS.VEHICLE_INFO ON TOKEN.VEHICLE_INFO_ID = VEHICLE_INFO.VEHICLE_INFO_ID
            UNION ALL
            SELECT TOKEN.CODE   
            FROM CMS.TOKEN 
            INNER JOIN CMS.VEHICLE_LINK_DATA  ON VEHICLE_LINK_DATA.TOKEN_ID = TOKEN.TOKEN_ID
            ); But with above pattern I am unable to generate them it should be something like start with INSERT INTO .* then either (SELECT( or SELECT( and end with semi colon

Comment: the regex i gave, filters sql queries 2 and 3 and also the additional example you gave here...under the condition that they are written in a _single_ line. do you have multi-line sql queries in your file? please provide a complete example in your question....

Comment: I have updated my description @mrxra

Comment: i've updated my response/regex. make sure you use multiline regexes. it finds all select based insert statements that ending in a ```;```. ```q``` is a list of insert statements, including any ```\n``` characters...you might want to filter them out depending on your needs...

Comment: Thank you so much for the response @mrxra 
I have added the my queries and resultant queries which I obtained through your regex there is slight pattern difference here is the sheet can you please look into it https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QOO4xNHP-mOhhUK6rRu_XwDV7C4iEip5GzbD_Qa55_s/edit

and secondly how can i make the output look more prettier or can write it into another file in the same pattern in which I read the file

Comment: see update: writes the found sql queries into a file ```OUT.SQL``` with the same formatting as they were provided in the input file...hope that helps

Comment: Great. but it is printing \r\n  such entities as well in the output I have attached the output in https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QOO4xNHP-mOhhUK6rRu_XwDV7C4iEip5GzbD_Qa55_s/edit . How can we add get the same as it was previously without  \r\n such lines in it

Comment: @mrzra I have given you the edit access of this file as well https://docs.google.com/document/d/1QOO4xNHP-mOhhUK6rRu_XwDV7C4iEip5GzbD_Qa55_s/edit and Thank a lot for this help!

Comment: it currently writes the sql statements the way they were formatted in the input file. what do you mean by _more pretty_? one query in one line (without \r\n)? if you need some sophisticated formatting, you should definitely use an sql parser

Comment: Thank you that's what I want :)

Comment: i've updated the example such that newlines and unnecessary whitespace is filtered out. each sql statement will be written into a single line.